# Thymeleaf table not displaying on html page in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table which is populated via a custom select statement to a database.
This has previously worked but now it is not displaying any values, not even the defaults.

I have created the table headings and here is the content declaration in the HTML:

```
<tr th:each="user : ${listUser}">
  <td>
    <a th:href="@{/editUser(user_id=${user.user_id})}">
      <span th:text="${user.user_id}">Default ID</span>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td th:text="${user.username}">Default username</td>
  <td th:text="${user.email_address}">Default email</td>
  <td th:text="${user.role_code}">Default role code</td>
  <td th:text="${user.enabled_ind}">Default enabled</td>
  <td>Default enabled</td>
</tr>
```

Here are the declarations in the Web Controller (The problems started when I added `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping`, it seems to be ignoring `@RequestMapping`.

```
@GetMapping("/admin")
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("searchuser", new Searchuser());
    return "admin";
}

@PostMapping("/userresults")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Searchuser searchuser) {
    return "userresults";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userresults")
public ModelAndView listUser(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
    List<User> listUser = userDAO.loadAllUser();
    model.addObject("listUser", listUser);
    model.setViewName("userresults");

    return model;
}
```

I know the SQL method is working as I have previously called it from another page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this table structure for displaying your data.

```
<table border="1" style="width: 300px">
    <tr>
        <th>User name</th>
        <th>Default Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="user : ${listUser}">
        <td th:text="${user.username}">Default username</td>
        <td>Default enabled</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**PS:** I tested your code with the above table structure and both `@GetMapping` and `@RequestMapping` is working fine. Also make sure the `listUser` has atleast one `User` otherwise even the default won't be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this has not resolved the problem though. I am shown the headings of the table but nothing within the body of the table. The listuser has a number of object but doesn't seem to want to display.

Comment: This same piece of code is working fine on my system.